# What's the difference between Android Studio install and "adb install"

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

When I install my app from Android Studio it works great but when I install it with `adb install <pc path to apk>` or `adb shell pm install -r <device path to apk>` the app fails to write a file to the device filesystem...

Does anyone know why? what's the difference? does installing with adb not give the app the permissions it wants?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

```
try {
        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        Element root = doc.createElement("map");
        doc.appendChild(root);
        buildCamCapabilitiesXML(cm.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraID), doc, root);
        writeXMLToFile(doc);
        renameFileAndDeleteOldOne(storagePath + fileName, new File(storagePath + fileName + FILE_TEMP_EXTENSION));
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to access camera to get camera abilities");
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get a DocumentBuilder");
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to write capabilities xml file to filesystem");
    }

private void writeXMLToFile(Document doc) throws TransformerException {
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(new File(storagePath + fileName + FILE_TEMP_EXTENSION)));
    }
```

Comment: Since Android Studio uses ADB to install the app, there is no difference.  What do you mean "the apps fails to write a file to the device filesystem"?  We need more detail.

Comment: There is no error or something its just not writing a file its supposed to write.
I have a script that waiting for a file that the app is supposed to create and the script just goes on an infinite loop since the app isnt writing the file.

Comment: There is an error, you just don't know how to use try..catch properly.  Please show the relevant code.

Comment: Check my edit.
There is no error in logcat.
Also the same app without ANY changes doesnt work when I install it with adb yet works perfectly fine when I install it with Android Studio.

Comment: Likely you are installing a different build in the two cases - the IDE is probably installing a different file than you think

Comment: Nope, I took the apk generated by the Android Studio

Comment: Even a succesfull install or run will generate logcat messages, so if you aren't seeing any you either aren't attempting those things or aren't using logcat right.

Comment: Where do you catch the `TransformerException`?

Comment: @Simon Added the proper code.

Comment: @ChrisStratton there are only 2 apks generated and both give the same behaviour

Comment: Well, looks OK.  Step through with the debugger, what happens?

Comment: I cant use the debugger since it reinstalls the app...

Comment: So what log messages are generated?

Comment: Only thin generated is this:
D/AndroidRuntime(26812):
D/AndroidRuntime(26812): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(26812): CheckJNI is OFF
D/AndroidRuntime(26812): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
D/AndroidRuntime(26812): Shutting down VM
I/art     (26812): Debugger is no longer active

And a couple of unrelated cpu leakages

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

Apparently the app had to be started once from the device after being installed by adb (which is done automatically in Android Studio).

After that it works perfectly, have no idea why though...